# CSS max-width not change value in media query

Tags: html, css, position

I set max-width on div which is positioned absolute. My problem is that when I set diffrent max-width value (%) on the diffrent screen size, it doesn't work as I would expect. For example, to set bigger value on smaller screen. Below is very simple example to show what's going on.

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (max-width:1200px) {
  
  div {
     max-width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rutrum elementum velit. Nullam imperdiet sem turpis, in auctor ante varius vel. Sed porttitor mauris eget dolor congue aliquam.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS *is* working. It's just that the div isn't being forced to its maximum width by its contents. Absolute positioning can be tricky.

Instead, set the `left` and `right` values to `0` for mobile, and set them to `35%` or `35vw` for desktop. You'll also need to remove your transform.

Suggestion: Set what's in your media query as the default (mobile-first), and override with a media query starting at 1200px.

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  right: 35%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width:1200px) {
  
  div {
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rutrum elementum velit. Nullam imperdiet sem turpis, in auctor ante varius vel. Sed porttitor mauris eget dolor congue aliquam.</div>
</body>
</html>
```